# http post request with x-auth(mean stack)

Tags: post, authorization, mean-stack

My mean stack sample application which i got from this link : https://github.com/dickeyxxx/mean-sample runs perfectly on my heroku server, posts and logins without any failure. It uses tokens when a post request is made. However, since i am not familiar with this system, i couldn't manage to post from postman to my local database when i run this server on (http://localhost:3000). Although i tried to put the token that has been created, to postman X-AUTH Header, i get this error : 
Error: Signature verification failed.

There is something wrong with decoding and encoding.

Fyi: Get request works and doesn't need any authorization. The only problem is sending post request from postman to the server running locally.

Any ideas how to send a post request from postman with x-auth?

Since i don't have a deep knowledge about this issue, i am not sure which line of code to add that may help. But some codes from the server;

> --Auth.js--

```
if (req.headers['x-auth']) {
    console.log(req.headers['x-auth']);
    req.auth = jwt.decode(req.headers['x-auth'], config.secret)
  }
```

> --Users.js--

```
var auth = jwt.decode(req.headers['x-auth'], config.secret)
  User.findOne({username: auth.username}, function (err, user) {
    if (err) { return next(err) }
    res.json(user)
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to take a shot at where you were going with this with the information provided...

**Advanced users see steps 1 & 2 below for the quick answer.**

First, your auth.js and users.js files are slightly modified from the original repo. It looks like they should still get the job done, but for anyone else following this answer, I'm referencing the ch8 branch of the git repo, as that is the chapter that deals with authorization. As usual, you will have to perform a "npm install" and perhaps troubleshoot any issues that occur when trying to get your localhost app up and running.

Because it wasn't explained what endpoints you were testing with or what parameters were used if any, I'll walk you through which ones should be used in case it wasn't what you were doing already.

To start, you can inspect what URL's are being called in your browsers web inspector, like Chrome inspector or Firebug for example. In Firebug, you would want to make sure you are looking at the "Console" tab, and from there, you can even right click the URL's and select "Copy as cURL" if you prefer to use the command line. The easiest way to find the endpoint you need, and the methods they use (like GET or POST) is to inspect what happens here when you login through the web application.

Assumptions:

- MongoDB is running locally
- Node is running your app locally with no errors being thrown
- You have already registered a user through the local running web app and are using this user's credentials to login

If all is well with the previous steps, proceed with the following in Chrome's Postman app:

### 1. Make a POST request to http://localhost:3000/api/sessions

- Make sure POST is selected from the method dropdown
- Be sure the "Headers" button is selected to view input boxes to edit Header information
- Put "Content-Type" (no quotes) for Header and "application/json" (no quotes) for the header value
- Select the "raw" button and put your JSON data for the user you previously registered in the textarea. Example JSON data: **{"username":"yourusername@example.com","password":"password"}**
- Hit "Send"

### 2. Make a GET request (not POST) to http://localhost:3000/api/users

- Copy the response (should be a JWT if everything went well) from your previous request
- Change the endpoint in Postman to http://localhost:3000/api/users
- Change the method to GET instead of POST
- Make a new Header (not a url parameter key, a Header) by putting "X-Auth" (no quotes) into Header, and paste your JWT response from earlier into the value (again no quotes)
- Hit "Send"

You should see a JSON object response with an _id property and a username property.

So, basically you shouldn't be making a POST request with an X-Auth header in the first place, only a GET request.